# How to CENTER IconButton in CircleAvatar with Stack Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So here's the situation. I want to build a Spotify-like button where the circular avatar is shown and on top of that, an icon button is been placed. I want to make the icon as much bigger to cover the whole avatar as possible but have failed after trying several answers already from this platform.

So, here's what I want. Center the IconButton in the avatar covering the whole size of the Circular Avatar. I'm attaching some screenshots as well as code. Have a look at it.

Thanks!

HERE's THE CODE

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddArtistWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddArtistWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      children: [
        const CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
          radius: 70,
        ),
        IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.add,
            size: 100,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

HERE's THE OUTPUT OF MY CODE

[image]

AND THAT's WHAT I WANT TO MAKE

[image]

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     Stack( alignment: Alignment.topCenter, 
children: [ const CircleAvatar( backgroundColor: Colors.black26, radius: 70, ), 
IconButton( padding: EdgeInsets.zero, onPressed: () {},
 icon: const Icon( Icons.add, size: 100,
 color: Colors.white, ), ), ], );
```

replace this with

```
 CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                radius: 70,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    size: 100,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: if you find it right don't forget to mark it accepted thankyou